# New mainboard for Shuttle

Tags: motherboard, case

I have an old Shuttle barebones SN21G5 (AMD 64), and I really need a more modern chip in there.

Is there a way of swapping out the old mainboard and putting in one of those new fangled phenom mainboards in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shuttle has their own form factor which you can only get from Shuttle themselves. I recommend skipping Shuttle altogether and sticking with a case where they don't make up their own form factor standards.

If you still want to keep the Shuttle computer and switch out the motherboard, you need to contact a Shuttle reseller for information on what your options are.

Comment: You're probably right, was just hoping...